# css - entire div is link inside the div - clickable - fiddle included

Tags: css, html, z-index

Div with heading and text inside.  When the div is hovered the background changes and a 'toast' rises from the bottom of the div.  Entire div is clickable based on the heading link and done in css.

The problem : in all versions of IE the link is only clickable when the cursor is NOT over text within the div (same problem in the fiddle example).  It works correctly in FF, Opera, and Safari.

JSFiddle - [the example](http://jsfiddle.net/Zp2Rp/1/)

```
<div class="one-third">
    <div class="inside">
        <h3><a href="/#">Testing</a></h3>
        <p>This some text inside the testing blox blah blah blah blah blah.</p>
        <p>and some more and some more.and some more and some morep>and some more and some moreand some more and some moreand some more and some moreand some more and some moreand some more and some moreand some more and some more.</p>
        <span class="toast">View more stuff</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.one-third{
    border:1px solid #d8d8d8;
    margin:35px 9px 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background:#ffffff;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding:25px 0 0 0;
}

.one-third:hover{ 
    background: #eeeeee;
}

.inside{
    height:185px;
}

.inside h3 a, .inside h3 a:hover{ /*entire div is link*/
    font-size: 20px;
    color:#30629a;
    text-decoration:none;
    position:absolute; 
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:13px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.inside p{
    padding:15px 15px 0 15px;
}


.toast{
    background: rgb(71, 71, 71); /* Fall-back for browsers that don't support rgba */
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: -30px;
    line-height:30px;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow:0 1px 1px #111111;
    font-size:14px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 0.1s linear 0s; /*no moz, webkit, or o because radius is needed and won't scroll right*/    
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
}

.one-third:hover .toast {
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution is to add

```
background:url("datdata:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7");
```

to .inside h3 a, .inside h3 a:hover. It's a base64 transparent gif that solves the problem for IE.

GIf found here: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/base64-encode-of-1x1px-transparent-gif/

Comment: Can you explain this a little more?  The link to the gif crashes IE on my end... I have a transparent gif of my own and adding it as a repeating background for the h3 a and h3 a:hover does nothing - same result.

Comment: That link does seem to crash IE, does this work? http://jsfiddle.net/Zp2Rp/27/ basically a base64 encoded image allows you to include an image in your CSS without the need for a separate image file, or http request to fetch it

Comment: Just tried it out and it works perfectly fine... not sure why it does right now lol, but will be looking into this a little more to find out.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to move the 'a' outside if the h3. IE is having a problem with that element being behind the 'p' tags.

```
<a href="/#"><h3>Testing</h3>
<p>...</p></a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Zp2Rp/14/

Comment: Yeah, I really don't want to the entire contents (text) of the div to be anchor text, but at the moment that is the only solution I came up with as well for IE.

Comment: Also, you technically shouldn't put block elements in an inline element... h1 is a block and a is inline.